# Makefile confusion phony hack

Tags: c, makefile

Folder structure:

- Makefile
- rect_01.c
- rect_02.c
- square_01.c

Makefile (relevant parts):

```
%.c:
    echo 'Building $@ for $(PLATFORM)...'
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ -o '$(DESTDIR)/$*'
```

Command:

```
make rect_01.c PLATFORM=FOO
```

Problem - gave me the output:

```
'rect_01.c up already to date'
```

So I tried a hack and added a dependency which I added to .Phony,
so that %.c should be executed every time. But now it tries to compile my
makefile even it hasn't the extension .c.

I wrote  the following updated makefile (relevant parts):

```
.PHONY: phonyDummy

%.c: phonyDummy
    echo 'Building $@ for $(PLATFORM)...'
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ -o '$(DESTDIR)/$*'
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
make rect_01.c PLATFORM=LINUX_X86
echo 'Building Makefile.c for LINUX_X86...'
Building Makefile.c for LINUX_X86...
g++ -Wall -g Makefile.c -o '../Executables/Makefile'
Makefile: file not recognized: File format not recognized
Makefile:55: recipe for target 'Makefile.c' failed
make: *** [Makefile.c] Error 1
```

Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: The output of a Makefile goes in the left side, not the input.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn more about `Makefile`. You mix two important things: target and dependency.

The target is a file (in most cases) which should create with a rule. The dependency is the "source".

If you write:

```
%.c:
    echo 'Building $@ for $(PLATFORM)...'
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ -o '$(DESTDIR)/$*'
```

it means: "I want to create files with `.c` extension". You don't want to create `.c` files because you've many (three) `.c` files. The `make` checks the `rect_01.c`: it exists and it's up-to-date because it hasn't any dependency (after the `:` there isn't anything).

I think you want to build `rect_01.so` (or similar) - this is the *target*! So you want similar:

```
%.o: %.c
    echo 'Building $@ for $(PLATFORM)...'
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

In this case if you want to build `rect_01.o` you should run `make rect_01.o`. The `$(CC)` will run if `rect_01.o` doesn't exist or older than `rect_01.c` (so the source `rect_01.c` is newer and doesn't rebuild yet).